# Oauth 2.0 and OpenId Connect for REST API authentication and authorization

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect

After having read books and watched videos on OAuth, OIDC, PKCE, JWT, etc. I still have no idea on how to use all of these for my app (a secured REST API).

My use case is fairly simple. I want my users to be able to login with Google, Amazon, Okta or whatever and the only info I want from them is the email address they used to login, nothing else. After their first login, their email will be added to a database and in a separate process I will grant them some permissions (what resources they can access).

So let's imagine a standard authorization code flow and let's fast forward to the access token part. The redirect URI has been called, we are in my client (somewhere is my backend/API) where I retrieve an access token. At this point the user has been successfully authenticated.

But what now ?

- I don't care about Google anymore (do I still need the access token ?), but I still want to check if the user can use my API for each request and is able to access the API resources depending on his permissions.
- How do I keep the user authenticated (for like 2h only) and check his permissions ? A session Cookie, a Token or something else with an expiration time ?
- Do I need my own authorization server to check if the user has access to the resource he is requesting ?
- Considering my requirements, do I need PKCE if the API is accessed from an SPA or a mobile app ? Wouldn't the authorization code flow be enough - the SPA or mobile app retrieve an authorization code, then call the callback endpoint from the API ?

And the more important question is, do I ask the right questions or am I completely off track and it's not how it's supposed to work ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your questions:

- Your API needs an access token on every request
- A stateless session is managed by sending the access token on every request
- It is recommended to use your own Authorization Server that manages redirecting to social providers - this will simplify your UIs and APIs which only need to handle one type of token - also this means you are in control of the tokens your apps use
- Yes - use PKCE for public clients - the Authorization Server and UI security libraries will handle this for you

Your use case is not simple at all on a technical level and requires a lot of understanding. A good starting point is to understand these aspects:

- Role of UI and what a coded solution looks like
- Role of Authorization Server and its configuration
- Role of API and what a coded solution looks like
- Open Id Connect messages used

These links of mine may be useful for browsing:

- [Initial code sample and tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)
- [Message Workflow including PKCE](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/)

Given an access token, both the UI and API can potentially get the email via step 12 in the second link to lookup user info.